# React Router Breadcrumbs use page titles instead of url dynamically

Tags: javascript, magento2.3.1, breadcrumbs, venia, react

I've got a magento 2.3.1 site with venia storefront a react front end and I'm trying to get the breadcrumbs to pull the page titles dynamically rather than pulling the url.

My current code for the breadcrumbs is as follows

```
import withBreadcrumbs from "react-router-breadcrumbs-hoc";
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'src/drivers';
import defaultClasses from "./breadcrumbs.css";
import classify from 'src/classify';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

const urlSuffix = '.html';

class Breadcrumbs extends Component {

    url(url){
        if(url ==='/')
        {
            return `${url}`
        }else {
            return `${url}`
        }
    }


    render () {

        const Breadcrumbs =  withBreadcrumbs()(({ breadcrumbs }) => (

            <ul className={defaultClasses.categorybreadcrumbs}>
                {breadcrumbs.map(({match, breadcrumb }) => (
                    <li key={match.url}>
                        <Link to={this.url(match.url)}>{breadcrumb}</Link>
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>

        ));

        return (<Breadcrumbs />)

    }
}

export default classify(defaultClasses)(Breadcrumbs);
```

I've tried to do something as long the lines of:

```
    const routes = [
        {
            path: {match.url}, breadcrumb: {page.title}
        }
    ]
```

But I don't seem to be having any luck achieve what I need.
At the moment it currently pulls the breadcrumbs using the URL of the pages and I need it to ideally use the Page titles instead, but it needs to happen dynamically as I can't add a route for every single page when there's thousands of product pages.

I've had a look for other react extensions but can't seem to find anything that does what I need.
Can anyone help? Any help would be greatly appreciated.